# connect to Interbase using ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, interbase

im trying to create a web page which connects to interbase database, can some one help me on how i might establish a connection to this database. if you have a code sample that would be great.

Comment: Embarcadero has released a new InterBase ADO.NET drivers for Visual Studio - https://blogs.embarcadero.com/embarcadero-expands-interbase-support-for-visual-studio/. Although a very old post but people end up to these question while searching for a solution to connect to InterBase with ASP.NET C# , so thought this comment may help them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article is a bit old but should be sufficient:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/IB_CS.aspx